# Regex with no 2 consecutive a's and b's

Tags: c, regex, regex-group

I have been trying out some regular expressions lately. Now, I have 3 symbols a, b and c.

I first looked at a case where I don't want 2 consecutive a's. The regex would be something like:

```
((b|c + a(b|c))*(a + epsilon)
```

Now I'm wondering if there's a way to generalize this problem to say something like:

A regular expression with no two consecutive a's and no two  consecutive b's. I tried stuff like:

```
(a(b|c) + b(a|c) + c)* (a + b + epsilon)
```

But this accepts inputs such as"abba" or "baab" which will have 2 consecutive a's (or b's) which is not what I want. Can anyone suggest me a way out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't do a negative match then perhaps you can use negative lookahead to exclude strings matching `aa` and `bb`? Something like the following (see [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/9EYwOn/1) for more information):

```
(?!.*(aa|bb).*)^.*$
```

Comment: This looks like a great idea indeed. Negative lookahead will do the trick. I'm accepting this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I (think I) solved this by hand-drawing a finite state machine, then, generating a regex using [FSM2Regex](http://ivanzuzak.info/noam/webapps/fsm2regex/). The state machine is written below (with the syntax from the site):

```
#states
s0
s1
s2
s3
#initial
s0
#accepting
s1
s2
s3
#alphabet
a
b
c
#transitions
s0:a>s1
s0:b>s2
s0:c>s3
s1:b>s2
s1:c>s3
s2:a>s1
s2:c>s3
s3:c>s3
s3:a>s1
s3:b>s2
```

[image]

If you look at the transitions, you'll notice it's fairly straightforward- I have states that correspond to a "sink" for each letter of the alphabet, and I only allow transitions out of that state for other letters (not the "sink" letter). For example, `s1` is the "sink" for `a`. From all other states, you can get to `s1` with an `a`. Once you're in `s1`, though, you can only get out of it with a `b` or a `c`, which have their own "sinks" `s2` and `s3` respectively. Because we can repeat `c`, `s3` has a transition to itself on the character `c`. Paste the block text into the site, and it'll draw all this out for you, and generate the regex.

The regex it generated for me is:

```
c+cc*(c+$+b+a)+(b+cc*b)(cc*b)*(c+cc*(c+$+b+a)+$+a)+(a+cc*a+(b+cc*b)(cc*b)*(a+cc*a))(cc*a+(b+cc*b)(cc*b)*(a+cc*a))*(c+cc*(c+$+b+a)+(b+cc*b)(cc*b)*(c+cc*(c+$+b+a)+$+a)+b+$)+b+a
```

Which, I'm pretty sure, is not optimal :)

EDIT: The generated regex uses `+` as the choice operator (usually known to us coders as `|`), which means it's probably not suitable to pasting into code. However, I'm too scared to change it and risk ruining my regex :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use back references to match the prev char

```
string input = "acbbaacbba";
string pattern = @"([ab])\1";
var matchList = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
```

This pattern will match: bb, aa and bb. If you don't have any match in your input pattern, it means that it does not contain a repeated a or b.

Explanation:

([ab]): define a group, you can extend your symbols here

\1: back referencing the group, so for example, when 'a' is matched, \1 would be 'a'

check this page: http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html